# Iterate over all partial "head" lists of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, iteration

Is there a "more Pythonic" way than:

```
l=list(range(5)) # ANY list, this is just an example
list(l[:i] for i in range(1, len(l)))

Out[14]: [[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

E.g. not using the index.

In C++ one can construct a sequence using a pair of (start, end) iterators. Is there an equivalent in Python?

Comment: You won't get more pythonic than a list comp with slicing.

Comment: `range(5)` is already a list; no need to cast.

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasimazar Not in Python 3.

Comment: good, didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, if you're aiming for "Pythonic", I think your current example of using indices are what most Python programmers would do.

That being said, you also mentioned creating an object using a pair of (start, end) values. Python has [slice](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-slice) objects, which is what the square bracket indices (the object's `__getitem__` call) internally uses. It can be created using the builtin `slice` function:

```
>>> my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> slice1 = slice(0, 3)
>>> slice1.start
0
>>> slice1.stop
3
>>> my_list[slice1]
[0, 1, 2]
>>> slice2 = slice(1, 2)
>>> my_list[slice2]
[1]
```

Of course this works only if `my_list` can be indexed. If you want this to work for iterables in general, @Hackaholic's answer using `itertools.islice` is what I would use.

And yes, this still means you will need to use the square bracket index eventually. The difference here is you're storing the (start, stop) value of the partial heads in objects you can use to actually create the partial heads.

Now to come back to your example:

```
>>> slices = [slice(0, x) for x in range(len(any_list))]
>>> partial_heads = [any_list[slc] for slc in slices]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `itertools.islice`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> l=list(range(5))
>>> [list(itertools.islice(l, x)) for x in range(1,len(l))]
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

you can check time of execution: There two factor memory performance and speed.

```
>>> timeit.timeit('[list(itertools.islice(l, x)) for x in range(1,len(l))]', setup='l=list(range(5))')
3.2744126430006872
>>> timeit.timeit('list(l[:i] for i in range(1, len(l)))', setup='l=list(range(5))')
1.9414149740005087
```

Here you go:

```
>>> [list(range(x)) for x in range(1, 5)]
[[0], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: Please comment for reason for downvote. so one can improve, just downvoting isn't helping anyone.

Comment: People don't have to give a reason on why they downvoted if they don't want to.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but you aren't really answering the question. The result has nothing to do with a rolling range. OP's trying to extract expanding slices from their list.

Comment: @JimFasarakisHilliard its a good practice to comment for improvement. Who said people dont' comment. its just your perception I think.

Comment: I'd be more concerned with fixing my answer than arguing... and Jim is right here, just for the record, there's been a long topic of discussion about justifying votes... and the verdict is you shouldn't be forced to do it if you don't want to.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ OP asked not use indexing, the answers is not using any indexing. is there anything i am missing to understand OP.

Comment: Yes, the answer also has nothing to do with `l`, which is what OP's question was meant for in the first place.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yes my answers is not using `l`. To generate sequence at some point you have provide limit.

Comment: From your reception to the downvotes, and subsequent criticism, it seems evident you have completely missed the point of the question. I don't think I can do anything more to make you understand, so I'll just leave it up to OP to clarify.

Comment: What coldspeed means is that the OP presumably has a generic list named `l`, and the one in the question is just a dummy example. In other words, the end result shouldn't always be a rolling range, it should rather be `[l[:1], l[:2], l[:3],...]`. If you modify your answer with this in mind you'll end up with OP's version, so your answer doesn't seem to add much.

Comment: I am not deleting the answer as the comment discussion  will be great help for other users to understand.

Comment: @Hackaholic it's your call, but the new `# ANY list, this is just an example` comment in the first line of the asker's code is a bit of a hint ;)